# Creating different User Types in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am planning to use AWS Amplify as a backend for a mobile application. The App consists of two User Types (UserTypeA,UserTypeB). They have some common data points and some unique one's too.

*UserTypeA(id, email, firstName, lastName, profilePicture, someUniquePropertyForUserTypeA)
UserTypeB(id, email, firstName, lastName, profilePicture, someUniquePropertyForUserTypeB)*

What would be a scalable approach to achieve this? I am also using AWS Amplify authentication so I can save the common data as CustomAttributes offered by Cognito, but then how would I save the uniqueProperties for the two user types. Will this approach scale?

This is a social app and is heavily reliant on other users' profile data as well (which will be queried most of the time).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the patterns that are recommended by AppSync (The graphQL service that is behind Amplify when adding graphQL API). It is described in detail here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authorization-use-cases.html

The main idea is to have multiple user pools defined in Cognito and then you can use the different groups in the resolvers. For example:

```
// This checks if the user is part of the Admin group and makes the call
#foreach($group in $context.identity.claims.get("cognito:groups"))
    #if($group == "Admin")
        #set($inCognitoGroup = true)
    #end
#end
#if($inCognitoGroup)
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "UpdateItem",
    "key" : {
        "id" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.id)
    },
    "attributeValues" : {
        "owner" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($context.identity.username)
        #foreach( $entry in $context.arguments.entrySet() )
            ,"${entry.key}" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($entry.value)
        #end
    }
}
#else
    $utils.unauthorized()
#end
```

or using the @directives on the graphQL schema, such as:

```
type Query {
   posts:[Post!]!
   @aws_auth(cognito_groups: ["Bloggers", "Readers"])
}

type Mutation {
   addPost(id:ID!, title:String!):Post!
   @aws_auth(cognito_groups: ["Bloggers"])
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Database design problem. To solve this, you can try creating a relation that has the common attributes in it, that is, `User` with attributes, `(ID, email, firstName, lastName, profilePicture, someUniquePropertyForUserTypeA)`.

After that, create sub-classed based relations, that is `UserTypeA`, and `UserTypeB`.

These relations will have a unique ID, and have a foreign key relation with the parent (`User`). How? The first major relation would be 'User'. The 2 sub classed relations would be 'UserTypeA', and 'UserTypeB'.

The 'User' has an attribute 'ID'.

So the two sub classes have an attribute, 'User_ID', which is a foregin relation to 'User'.'ID'.

Now just autogen another ID column for `UserTypeA` and `UserTypeB`.

This way, you have a central table which has a unique ID for all users, and then you have a unique ID in each of the sub class relations, which together with `User_ID` forms a composite key.

Comment: Amplify Datastore uses a NoSql database (dynamo DB). The DataStore is a kind of an ORM that translates the graph QL schema over this database. So this is more of a GraphQL scheme design problem, than a relational ERD problem. Moreover, AWS Amplify Auth uses AWS Cognito which allows us to store some genric user related data as well (custom_attributes) which can be used.
Maybe you can better understand this by going to https://sandbox.amplifyapp.com/getting-started -> Data section

Comment: Best. Sure, I'll go through this. Missed the mark here.